# To extract the skills required for the job given the job description

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, nlp

1. Any recommendation on the libraries/methods to extract the skill set required for the job from the job description (raw text) ?
2. And also to extract the skillset from the resume ? The resume could be of any format raw text, pdf, docx.

[image]

I have attached the job description format.

Comment: The question is to broad. Would you provide some examples of the data?

Comment: Hi, I have added the sample description. However, this format could differ from employer to employer. I am looking for a flexible tool that go through the entire job description and extract the required skill needed

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you already have the raw text, you can do the followings.

**Create train data:**

You need to create set words and bigrams labeled as skills. There might be some available lists to help you out. Otherwise, generate your list using resources such as wordnet and thesaurus. You can also start with a short list based on the data you have and then expand it using word2vec or similar word embedding techniques. For example, we start with a list that contains *coding* as one of the skills. Then, we query the word2vec pretrained model for closest words/bigrams. There is a fair chance you will end up with *programming*, *software coding*, and *computer programming*.

Another approach would be to cluster the words and bigrams in your dataset using word embedding techniques. Then, look into your clusters to see which ones contain the skill set.

Note that any word/expression not on your list will not be considered as required skills. Therefore, you may need to expand your list after a few trials.

**Detecting the Skills**

1. Tokenize your raw text into words and expressions
2. Remove stop words
3. Encode your tokens using an embedding (Word2Vec, FastText, etc)
4. Use the list from the previous step to add labels to your data (anything on the list is True, other as False)
5. Train a binary classifier (Naive Bayes classifier should be good enough)
6. Evaluate your model, feature set, and labels. If needed, refine and repeat.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do some web scraping. [This](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2015/10/beginner-guide-web-scraping-beautiful-soup-python/) resource may be useful to you, it explains how to do web scraping with Beautiful Soup, a very common python package. However, web scraping is never an easy task because webpages are rarely formatted in a friendly way.

Comment: Its more of a NLP/machine learning problem to get the skills out of raw text. I do have access to the job description content.

Answer (score 0):

In what format are your input texts provided?

- If it is *HTML* then use a library that selects (for instance) from the Document Object Model DOM all paragraphs following "Requirements". In javascript you could use jQuery, or on the linux command line you could use the xmllint binary (which uses xml2 internally). Many other libraries are available.
- If it is *PDF* then doing this is more difficult.

After that you could do some bag-of-words modeling as user "Borhan Kazimipour" has suggested in another answer.

Or you could topic-model them. Probabilistic Topic Modeling is a more difficult technique which would take me at least a week to re-learn the principles of, and to get familiar with available command line tools and libraries.